# alternative to 'code' visual studio in pycharm

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Some of my coworkers use visual studio code. Personally I am already used to pycharm. I've seen my colleagues using `code filename` in the VSC terminal, so that it opens the file `filename` in a new VSC tab. Is there a similar alternative in pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create a CLI launcher in the Tools menu "Create Command-line launcher"
The last part of the path is the name you decide to give the launcher e.g "pcharm" or "pyc" (anything of your choice) and save it.
Reload the terminal, and run the command with your file name.